# Is there a way to reset or recalculate vertex indices in a mesh?

Tags: vertices

I have 2 meshes with the same topology, slightly different geometry, different vertex indexes. I'd like to make one a shapekey of the other, however the vertex indexes not being the same prevents 'join as shapes' from working. Does anyone know how/if this is possible?

Comment: You may be able to get some use out of sort mesh elements operation (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/sort_elements.html)